# Получить токен пользователя без запуска приложения (онлайн дебагер как в FB)

Tags: одноклассники

Нужно написать серверную часть для API (валидация токена и т.п). Для этого нужны токены пользователей. Но нет желания возиться с клиентом.

У FB, к примеру, есть [онлайн дебагер](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/v2/). Токен пользователя можно получить в нём, даже не создавая клиентское приложение. Для бекендщиков очень удобно.

Есть ли что-то такое в Одноклассниках? В [доках](https://apiok.ru/dev/sdk/) ничего подобного не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На странице конкретных методов API можно получить токен. К примеру, на странице метода [`users.getCurrentUser`](https://apiok.ru/dev/methods/rest/users/users.getCurrentUser).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь и OAuth токен можно получить, и сам метод продебажить.